# Windows 2008 Radius Client

Tags: windows-server-2008, radius

I'm trying to search for a way to have Windows 2008 as a Radius client to authenticate itself with the corporate Radius server. AD is currently out of the picture, and my superiors want me to look into integrating it with Radius. Although, in essence, I don't think it will work.

So, is there an application or a feature to enable in Windows 2008 to configure it as a Radius client?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Requests for product recommendations are off-topic here, and could get your question closed.  So I removed that part of the question.

Comment: Tried Google? Tried anything? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732929(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty What you are mentioning is for adding Radius clients on Windows 2008 Server acting as a Radius server. I want to make windows 2008 a Radius client. Anyways I found an application after several hours of looking around. It's called pGINA. I still didn't test it though.